# R- Error in `[.data.frame`(rows, ID == 1) : object 'ID' not found

Tags: r

Following function reads a directory full of files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file. The function should return a data frame where the first column is the name of the file and the second column is the number of complete cases. A prototype of this function follow

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {
        ##set up directory
        file_names <-
            dir(paste("C:/Users/Bruce/Desktop",directory,sep = "/"))
        ## combine the 332 files into data frame in the directory
        data_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv))
        ## complete case
        good <- complete.cases(data_frame)

        rows <- data_frame[good,]
        ##structure of data_frame
        str(rows)


        nobs = vector(, 400)
        for(i in id){
            nobs <- nrow(rows[which(ID == 1),])
        }

        cbind(id, nobs)

    }

    complete("specdata")
```

Errors

```
 > complete("specdata")
    'data.frame':   111802 obs. of  4 variables:
     $ Date   : Factor w/ 4018 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 279 285 291 297 303 315 321 327 333 339 ...
     $ sulfate: num  7.21 5.99 4.68 3.47 2.42 1.43 2.76 3.41 1.3 3.15 ...
     $ nitrate: num  0.651 0.428 1.04 0.363 0.507 0.474 0.425 0.964 0.491 0.669 ...
     $ ID     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     Show Traceback

     Rerun with Debug
     Error in `[.data.frame`(rows, ID == 1) : object 'ID' not found
```

The Result should be like:

```
complete("specdata", c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
##   id nobs
## 1  2 1041
## 2  4  474
## 3  8  192
## 4 10  148
## 5 12   96
```

Comment: I think there are many dupes for this question.  Please google it for specdata

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know the reason for this error

Comment: I think you want to use `id` not `ID`. R is case sensitive.

Comment: Try rows[which(rows$ID == 1),]

Comment: Please don't use `$` inside a function.  try `rows[,id]==1`

Comment: @henning lee the reason is the vector ID is not attached to the environment so it needs to be accessed by using $ or using the column index as in akrun s comment

Comment: @VikramVenkat there is no variable called `ID`. There is an `id`, though.

Comment: @Roman lustrik I'm afraid not, because ID is present in the output of the str function

Comment: @VikramVenkat it would appear both versions appear (see the last chunk). A better representation of the data or a reproducible example would be something to go for, here.

Comment: @VikramVenkat, it works, thank you